# JavaFX Change Alert Dialog Button's text

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

```
public void PersianStandardDialog(String title,String header,String context) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setHeaderText(header);
    alert.setContentText(context);

    Scene scene = alert.getDialogPane().getScene();
    scene.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    Stage standarddialogStage = (Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();

    Button okButton = (Button) alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton( ButtonType.OK );
    okButton.setText("Accept.");

    // Add a custom icon.
    standarddialogStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:resources/images/calendar.png"));

    alert.showAndWait();
}
```

Everything is OK, but When I want to use Unicode characters the result is '????' . How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How are you passing/setting the unicode characters to the button?

Comment: For example : okButton.setText("قبول");

Comment: Have you tried using [unicode escapes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3)?

Comment: Do you know any prepared function for using Unicode escape?